# How to create negative concave shape

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

i want to create a div tag with special image background like this
[concave http://cubeupload.com/im/nZDFtO.png](http://cubeupload.com/im/nZDFtO.png)

i am using the following code to create a concave shape:

```
    .slide2:before
    {

background:black;
    background-size:cover;
    height: 50px;
    z-index:0;
    width: 100%;
      border-radius:50% 50% 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;

    left: 0;
    }
```

but now i want something reverse.  i am using the following command but it doesn't work

border-radius:-50% -50% 0px 0px;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this kind of shape using a pseudo element and large box shadow:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  left: -10%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 120%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px green;
}
html,
body {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(79, 79, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

If, however, you were using a solid colored background, you could use something like:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(79, 79, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1) 100%);
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  left: -10%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 120%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:white;
}
html,
body {

  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that like that in CSS. There is a good documentation at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

But what you could do is to lay one element on top of the other using the z-index, with the top element using the style and the bottom element being the image.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your excact needs, you can get pretty close with some css3. Using markup like this:

```
<div class="concave">
</div>
<div class="concave flip-vertical">
</div>
<div class="concave rotate-vertical">
</div>
```

and css like this:

```
    .concave
    {
        background: black;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 50px;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 50% 50% 0px 0px;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 200px;
    }

    .flip-vertical
    {
        -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1,-1);
        -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
        transform: scale(1, -1);
    }

    .rotate-vertical
    {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
```

You get something like this:

[image]

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/32wH8/) is a jsFiddle to play with. Only problem is that this only works in IE9+, which sadly still leaves out quite a lot of people.

Edit: If you only want a thin sliver (border), simply replace `background: black;` with `border-top: 1px solid black;`.

Updated fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/32wH8/1/).